# Drawing an Oval with dashed rectangle around it

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, shapes

I just have a simple question:

Is there a method in graphics that allows you to draw an oval or circle with a rectangle border around it? Or is that a method that you would have to do on your own.

Comment: What GUI library? Swing? If so, you can create Shapes or use the Graphics or Graphics2D methods.

Answer (score 0):

Draw each one separately.

Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html) for drawing a rectangle with dashed line.

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for drawing oval.